# Call JavaScript Constructor using an array for the arguments

Tags: javascript, constructor

I have a constructor function in JavaScript as below and want to supply constructor arguments from an array:

```
 function dataRow(value1, value2, value3, value4, value5) {
                this.val1 = value1;
                this.val2 = value2;
                this.val3= value3;
                this.val4 = value4;               
                this.val5 = value5;
}
```

Now I want the constructor arguments supplied from an array:

```
var dataArray = new Array();

dataArray("Value1","Value2","Value3","Value4","Value5","Value6"...........)
```

I want (value1, value2, value3, value4, value5) this part to filled from my `dataArray`.

Comment: Java != JavaScript. They're completely different languages.

Comment: Also note that the overwhelming convention in JavaScript is that constructor function names start with a capital letter, to differentiate them from other non-constructor functions.

Answer (score 6):

In modern environments, you can use [spread notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax):

```
var row = new dataRow(...dataArray);
```

```js
function dataRow(v1, v2, v3, v4, v5) {
  this.v1 = v1;
  this.v2 = v2;
  this.v3 = v3;
  this.v4 = v4;
  this.v5 = v5;
}

var dataArray = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
var row = new dataRow(...dataArray);
console.log(row.v1);
console.log(row.v2);
console.log(row.v3);
console.log(row.v4);
console.log(row.v5);
```

In older environments, it's a real pain to do this. In your specific case, probably just do it the hard way:

```
dataRow(dataArray[0], dataArray[1], dataArray[2], dataArray[3], dataArray[4]);
```

Or you can separate creation from the call, and call it with [`Function#apply`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply):

```
var row = Object.create(dataRow.prototype);
dataRow.apply(row, dataArray);
```

```js
function dataRow(v1, v2, v3, v4, v5) {
  this.v1 = v1;
  this.v2 = v2;
  this.v3 = v3;
  this.v4 = v4;
  this.v5 = v5;
}

var dataArray = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
var row = Object.create(dataRow.prototype);
dataRow.apply(row, dataArray);
console.log(row.v1);
console.log(row.v2);
console.log(row.v3);
console.log(row.v4);
console.log(row.v5);
```

That wouldn't work with a constructor created via `class`, but if you're creating it via `class`, use spread notation; they were introduced as the same time (ES2015).

---

I would suggest **not** doing this, though, especially in light of [your comment below](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50760974/call-javascript-constructor-using-an-array-for-the-arguments/50761012#comment88532358_50761012):

> ...how to create this dynamically this.val1 = value1; this.val2 = value2; this.val3= value3;...

Instead, use a single array property, and pass in an array which you either keep or copy:

```js
function dataRow(values) {
  this.values = values;
  // or: this.values = values.slice();
  // to make a shallow copy
}

var dataArray = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
var row = new dataRow(dataArray);
console.log(row.values);
```

Comment: Thank You for the reply i created below code from your suggestion function dataRow(){


}
 var row = Object.create(dataRow.prototype);

   dataRow.apply(row, dataArray); but its not working as well how to create this dynamically this.val1 = value1;
                this.val2 = value2;
                this.val3= value3;

Comment: *"but its not working"* Yes, it works; see the live snippets above. *"how to create this dynamically this.val1 = value1; this.val2 = value2; this.val3= value3;"* Don't. Pass the array into the constructor, and then use an array: `this.values = values;` or `this.values = values.slice();` if you want to (shallow) copy the passed-in array.

Comment: I got your point:

But in below code snippet i dont want to add the below code manually 

that is V1,v2,v3, this should be passed from array dynamically depending upon the number of items in a array variable 
as well i should be able pass this.v1 = v1; this.v2 = v2; this.v3 = v3; this.v4 = v4; from another variable 

function dataRow(v1, v2, v3, v4, v5) {
  this.v1 = v1;
  this.v2 = v2;
  this.v3 = v3;
  this.v4 = v4;
  this.v5 = v5;
  
}

Comment: @KumarWarthak - If you pass in the array, you can do string concatenation to create the property names: `value.forEach((value, index) => this["v" + (index + 1)] = value; })`. But I wouldn't.

Comment: If i have a two dataarray like:

dataarray =["Value1","Value2","Value3","Value4","Value5","Value6"...........]

dataarray1=["this.Value1 = v1;,this.Value2 = v1;,this.Value3 = v1;,this.Value4= v1;, "]

i want to use it as below:

function dataRow(dataarray) {
 dataarray1
  }